# Gained rep after editing a question?

Tags: support

I edited this question to fix a typo: **[How can Star Trek: Countdown ever be considered canon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-can-star-trek-countdown-ever-be-considered-canon)**

However, in my rep overview I see that I have gained rep for it (2 points).

[image]

All I can find is this question which has *not* resulted in a new feature: [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)

So, can anyone tell me what happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [a new feature.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep/77508#77508)

Oddly, they have not blogged about, nor updated the FAQs, nor updated the privileges.

Comment: There's a blog post now: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/