# Why am I not getting rep increases for edits?

Tags: support, reputation, editing, suggested-edit

[I used to get rep updates for editing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/gained-rep-after-editing-a-question). I completely forgot about this benefit until I edited on a different SE site and my rep inches up by 2.

Why is it not happening here anymore? Are these increases only for *suggested* edits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You stop getting rep for editing once you (a) have received 1,000 rep for suggested and accepted edits, or (b) have gained the Edit privilege at 2,000 rep (1k on betas; 20k for edits to tag wikis (4k on betas)).  You have 7k here so your edits to posts are final, not suggested, and so you don't get the rep from *suggested* edits.

Answer (score 4):

You only get reputation for *suggested edits* (that have to be approved by someone), not for edits that you make unsupervised. Above 2000 rep, you can edit posts without supervision and you don't gain reputation from it. The limit is 20k rep for tag wikis. There's also a cap: you won't gain more than 1000 rep from editing altogether on any given site.

For more on suggested edits, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Comment: Not quite, 1,000 is the (lifetime) cap on rep from suggested edits; you can suggest edits (and so still get the rep, as long as you haven't hit the edit-specific cap) until you hit the edit privilege at 2k.

Comment: @Kevin I did not realize that... probably because I have mostly hit that 1k mark on sites still in beta.   That's good to know.  Thanks!